# AngularJS - Directive DOM manipulation / changing dynamic elements isn't updating view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/16844/

In my app I've tried to manipulate elements via an onClick directive, which seems to be changing the controller's variables/objects, as it's logging the new values to the console correctly, but this isn't showing in the view itself.

For example, I have a filled notifications array, which is cleared in the directive using .length = 0, and when I log the array to the console it shows that it is empty, but in the view, where items are repeated in an ng-repeat list, the list is still populated with the items from the array in its initial populous state.

None of the changes in my directive update the view, but when I do the same actions in a controller function, the view updates as it should.

Directive:

```
app.directive('clearNotifications', function($mdDialog, $mdToast, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'notificationsController',
    controllerAs: 'notifications',
    scope: false,
    bindToController: true,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        var notifications = $scope.notifications;
        console.log('notifications.test: ' + notifications.test);
        /* Show confirmation prompt dialog */
        var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
          .parent(angular.element('body'))
          .clickOutsideToClose(true)
          .title('Are you sure you want to clear all notifications?')
          .textContent('This action cannot be undone.')
          .ariaLabel('Confirm notifications list clearance')
          .ok('Yes')
          .cancel('No')
          .targetEvent(element)
        /* On confirm */
        $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
            $scope.status = 'All notifications deleted';
            console.log($scope.status);
            /* Show notifications list loader */
            $scope.showLoader = true;
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.showLoader = false;
            }, 1000)
            /* Clear notifications array */
            notifications.notifications.length = 0;
            console.log($scope.notifications.notifications);
            $scope.noNotifications = true;
            /* Reset filters to 'All' default */
            notifications.filters = angular.copy(notifications.resetFilters);
            /* Show toast */
            //$scope.toastTitle = 'TEST';
            $mdToast.show(
              $mdToast.simple()
              .content('All notifications cleared')
              .action('Close')
              .position('bottom right')
              .hideDelay(500000)
            )
          },
          /* On cancel */
          function() {
            $scope.status = 'Notifications clearance cancelled';
            console.log($scope.status);
          })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I fixed the fiddle.js, 'items' was never being denied to scope: http://jsfiddle.net/c9v83vo4/, hope that helps

Comment: I've tested this now and it still doesn't update the view